# ~bashrc file content deleted

Tags: ros, bashrc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like I have deleted content of this file by adding somthing wrong. Since I've had a longer break in my work can't really remember what did I do.
But, when I open it (gedit ~/.bashrc) it is completely empty

Since I am a total beginner and don't really know what happened can someone please give me some idea about what to do and what does this even mean for my further work.
thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196508/%7Ebashrc-file-content-deleted/) by [gwtw](https://answers.ros.org/users/20675/gwtw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Normally when you installed ROS you added the following line to your .bashrc

> source /opt/ros/indigo(or any other distro)/setup.bash

This is only done for more convenience and if you only use one ROS disto. The content of a .bashrc is executed automatically whenever you open a terminal in order to setup some environment variables (telling linux where to find ROS). I don't know what implications a missing bashrc would have on linux but for ROS you just need to run the command I mentioned above in every new terminal you open and eventually also source any other workspaces you are using. Mostly it would look like this

> source /home/user_name/some_workspace/devel/setup.bash

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-11-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you've completely erased your ~/.bashrc, you can replace it by copying /etc/skel/.bashrc (This is the template that the user creation script used to create your bashrc).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2